# How to get chrome browser Cookies and use in IE browser

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have 10 test cases 
one to five test cases i want to run in chrome browser using selenium (java) and six to ten test cases i want to run in IE browser

in 1 to 5 test cases 
login and all other functions 
and 6 to 10 test cases 
without login use chrome browser Cookies & start the IE browser

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, we can't help without [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve and set cookies in the WebDriver using these two methods:

`webDriver.manage().getCookies();`

`webDriver.manage().addCookie(cookie);`

If this isn't what you're looking for, please provide an example of your issue.

Comment: How to switch my IE browser session to chrome browser session?

My 'sign in' is in IE browser and after sign in if i click on the links(session lost also there i can't copy the url and open in Chrome using driver.get(url)) they get opened in chrome browser. How to switch my current browser from IE to chrome during the same Test case.

Comment: You'll have to manually launch a WebDriver for Chrome. But I think you also need to ask yourself why you need to test something that a user will is very unlikely to do.

Comment: Its a Requirement from client and somehow i managed.